# Etymology of "vector field" vs "algebraic field" -- are they related?

Tags: field-theory, soft-question, terminology, math-history, vector-fields

A [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Vector_fields_on_subsets_of_Euclidean_space) in a Euclidean space is typically represented by a function $F\colon S\to\mathbb{R}^N$, where $S\subset \mathbb{R}^N$.

An [algebraic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) is a space which has some nice properties.

**Is there a mathematical reason both of phrases use the term** ***field***? Is there some way we can view one in terms of the other? It looks like the answer is no, but I am not an algebraist. **If not, which phrase originated first**?

Comment: The field of the vector field seems to come from physics, as in electromagnetic fields and such. The field of the algebraic field (a commutative unitary ring where all non-zero elements are invertible) originates, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics), from some english speaking dude. In western languages the term for an algebraic field is "body" (translated to english). Regardless of which came first, they seem to be entirely unrelated.

Comment: Thanks, @LetGBeTheGraph ! This answers my question, if you could please post it then I can close the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mathematical reason both contain the term field; it's simply etymology.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any insights on the history of the two terms -- or which appeared first?

Comment: It feels like in those kinds of answers, where truth cannot be verified by reasoning, references should be provided.