# Do algebraic fields in mathematics have any connection to the fields in physics?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Basic question, but is there some sort of connection between the two, or are they just separate definitions.

Comment: I believe OP is talking about fields, as in the class of rings.

Comment: No, fields in algebra are not fields in physics. In French and German they have different names.

Comment: Oh man @ElliotG LOL I think you're right. To answer the question: it *really* depends. Almost always no because when physicists call something a field, they typically mean a vector or tensor field (or something related). In mathematical physics, you might get authors being particular about their word usage in which case they might mean $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ (or something more exotic) when they say field.

Comment: Well, there are *vector fields*...and I believe it is the same in mathematics and in physics.

Comment: @AnginaSeng indeed! At least in French, German and (sometimes) in Spanish the literal translation to English of the word used for *field* (in the algebraic sense) is *body*.

Comment: In physics the word *field* has a different meaning - consider, say, $2$-dimensional conformal field theory.

Comment: This was asked a little while ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757022/etymology-of-vector-field-vs-algebraic-field-are-they-related#comment7728108_3757022

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín I met Gonzalo Ares de Parga in UCSD. He was my office mate for sometime. Is he your family ?.

Comment: Hi @FelixMarin , yes Gonzalo is my uncle! How small is the world right? I’ll ask him about you, I’m sure he’ll remember you. Saludos!

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín I tried to reach him by email but he never answered.

Comment: @FelixMarin I know that he has had issues with his email account for a long time. If you want, you can send me your info to my email (all my info is on my website listed on my profile here) and I’ll sent it his way!

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín 0 k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different things. Algebraically fields are just a number system. Good examples are the rational, real, and complex numbers.

In physics fields are typically vector functions over some domain, often real valued. An example would be a function that returned air pressure given some point on Earth. They're only related in so much as fields play an important role in defining vector spaces.

Comment: In gauge theory I guess most of the fields are not real-valued. They have value in a group.

Comment: @ArcticChar I have seen vector valued fields as well which is why I included the caveat.